# Signing JWT with AzukeKeyVault Key

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I've got to sign JWT with Key stored in AzukeKeyVault, but struggle to get it to work, solutions I've used so far aren't working or are using Secrets instead of Keys to store RSA Key (unless I'm wrong and RSA key should be stored as Secret?)

```
        JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, jwtPayload);
        string encodedJwt = jwt.EncodedHeader + "." + jwt.EncodedPayload;
        byte[] encodedJwtBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedJwt);
        KeyOperationResult signature = await keyVaultClient.SignAsync(keyId, "RS256", new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(encodedJwtBytes));
        string jwtString = encodedJwt + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature.Result);
```

Comment: In normal, we should use azure key vault key to sign jwt. COuld you please provide the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sign jwt, we should use azure key vault key. Regarding how to do that, please refer to the following code

1. Create a service principal.
2. Configure access policy fo the sp
3. Code

```
           #create rsa key
            var clientId = "42e0d080-****c522d988c4";
            var secret = "Gbx2eK64i***.ClJDfQpIjoae:";
            var tenant = "e4c9ab4e-bd2***0ba2a757fb";
            var creds = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant, clientId, secret);
            var keyClient = new KeyClient(new Uri("https://jimkey02.vault.azure.net/"), creds);
            string rsaKeyName = "testkey";
            var rsaKey = new CreateRsaKeyOptions(rsaKeyName, hardwareProtected: false)
            {
                KeySize = 2048,
            };
            await keyClient.CreateRsaKeyAsync(rsaKey);
            
            #sign
             var claimsToSign = new[]
            {
              new Claim("sub", "1234567890"),
              new Claim("name", "John Doe")
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(

                claims: claimsToSign
            );

            var header = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                  {JwtHeaderParameterNames.Alg, "RS256" },
                  {JwtHeaderParameterNames.Typ, "JWT"}
             }));

            var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header + "." + token.EncodedPayload);
            var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
            var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);
             KeyVaultKey key = await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(rsaKeyName);
            var cryptClient = new CryptographyClient(key.Id, creds);
            var signature = await cryptClient.SignAsync("RS256", digest);
            var fullJwt = $"{header}.{token.EncodedPayload}.{Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature.Signature)}";
            Console.WriteLine(fullJwt);

            var kid = key.Key.Id.Substring(key.Key.Id.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(key.Key);
            var jk = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JsonWebKey(jsonString)
            {
                Kid = kid
            };
```